# 'src' folder in downloader folder

Tags: magento-1.6, downloader

I just took over a new site and I'm seeing some weird files in source control. In the downloader folder, there's a folder 'includes/src' that has all the controllers for all the modules on the system, including Magento modules.

I understand that if you enable compilation mode, the includes/src folder will contain files. Compilation mode is off for the site.

I'm about 95% sure that removing the folder (at least from source control) will be fine, but does anyone know what this could be about?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know much about compilation myself, but I have seen this before. Chances are that it is left over from when someone had turned compilation on before and it probably can be removed without consequence.